# Passing an id from View to a new html.ActionLink()

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem sending an ID from a View to a controller and back to another view via actionLink()

```
@model Mooshak2._0.Models.ViewModels.UserHomeViewModel

@foreach (var n in Model.Assignments)
{
        @Html.ActionLink(n.Name, "StudentAssignments", "User", new { id = n.ID}, null)
}
```

I'm trying to send the specified Assignment ID to the StudentAssignment View but can't seem to figure out how to implement it.

Here is a part of the UserController:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Students")]
public ActionResult StudentAssignment()
{
    return View(); 
}
```

And the StudentAssignment is supposed to just show the name of the assignment:

```
@model Mooshak2._0.Models.ViewModels.AssignmentViewModel

<h1>@Model.Name</h1>
```

In the UserHomeViewModel i have a

```
public List<AssignmentViewModel> Assignments { get; set; }
```

and the AssignmentViewModel contains all the details including the name which i cant seem to figure out how to get. Any ideas on how to pass the id to the view with the actionLink? Is the problem in the ActionLink or in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for. You are passing an `id` parameter but not taking this parameter in the controller ;

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Students")]
public ActionResult StudentAssignment(int id)
{
    return View(); 
}
```

Edit: Oh, @Mostafizur Rahman has already made the required comment. Sorry

Comment: But when i try to open the studentassignment view i still get an error saying : "The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. " and Requested URL: /User/StudentAssignments/7 but there is an assignment in the database with id = 7. Is it possible that i have the actionresult in the controller in the wrong controller?

Comment: You should check your `User` controller. It has to contains `StudentAssignment` method like you have below. that url means that.

Comment: Oh yeah nevermind, it was named StudentAssignment, not StudentAssignments. Thanks for your help!